# Unable to install software from Atomic Toolkit - 18.04

Tags: plex

Currently running a fresh install of 18.04 desktop.

I used **Atomic Toolkit** to set up some software on 16.04 and it worked flawlessly however I'm running into some issue.

When I try to install anything in Atomic Toolkit I get the below error.

**AtoMiC Mono Installer Script
Invalid option or feature not implemented yet**

I've installed Mono separately and my OS is up to date etc

All help appreciated :) [image]

Answer (score 0):

There's a known issue with the new Mono, they are working on a fix now.

https://github.com/htpcBeginner/AtoMiC-ToolKit/issues/281